# Trig Question with angles of elevation

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

A UFO is flying above two people standing on the ground at points A and B.

A and B are 300m apart.

The angle of elevation of UFO from A is 30 degrees

The angle of elevation of the UFO from B is 23 degrees

Find height of UFO above ground.

I got something like 480m but apparently that's wrong, I'm really not sure how I've gone wrong, if anyone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h$ be the height of the UFO. If you consider the triangle $AUB$  you can find the $h$ as below:[image]

$x=\frac{h}{\tan(23)}$ and $y=\frac{h}{\tan(30)}$.

$x+y=300 \rightarrow \frac{h}{\tan(30)}+\frac{h}{\tan(23)}=300$

Comment: why is this the case?

Comment: is this question possible to solve with sine law?

Comment: @Drwhops Consider the two smaller right triangles and what the tangent of each angle (20 degrees and 23 degrees. I don't think any simple use of the sine laws will help because the height of the UFO is not one of the sides of the ABU triangle.

Comment: Got it now thanks